# Android Search Dialog and Suggestions ListView: Change theme and colours

Tags: android, android-theme

I've implemented a simple search dialog that performs a custom search of the data within my app (Via a custom provider) as according to the guidelines here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

The problem is that the search bar's colors and size (exceeds the height of the action bar, etc) do not work within the design of my app. I know how to create a theme in my styles.xml file, but I do not know how to target the Android search dialog and suggestions listView. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 13 hours spent on the question, it turns out it's not possible for some reason. Apps that do have visually customized search dialogs- even if it's just the colours - must implement them manually, and probably don't use the standard search interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

as per google docs SearchDialog is

"The search dialog is a UI component that's controlled by the Android system."

So to have a control over search visuals use as for today  :

ActionBarSherlock dev branch

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/dev

and this :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#ConfiguringWidget

to implement fully controlable search