# How can I show multiple areas of search suggestions for Android search suggestions?

Tags: android

I have an iPhone app with search suggestions that divides the search suggestions into "your query text appears in the name" and "your query text appears somewhere else in the description". The thinking is that users are most likely to be searching by name, so we show those suggestions first.

[image: iPhone suggestions]

I'd like to do the same thing with the Android version of the app., but so far I haven't worked out how — so all of the suggestions are being shown in one big long list.

[image: Android suggestions]

How do I show search suggestions split up into two different areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking around for a while, and so far I haven't seen any way of dividing up search suggestions into multiple areas (at least without implementing your own search system), or even any app that does this.

Answer (score 0):

use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) instead of `ListView`

Comment: How do I get the search suggestion list to use an ExpandableListView? That's not a list I'm creating myself, it's placed there as part of the system search UI.

Comment: ...and from another question, it looks like this might not be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9087268/633626.